# Response to my counter offer

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process

I applied for a job in August, and was extended an offer letter by a globally renowned organization on Dec 06 after the fourth round of interviews on November 30. I emailed back to see if there was a possibility to have the salary increased by $6,000 based on market value, and the recruiter responded on December 11 as follows: “I will share this information with the Human Resources business partner, and let you know when we have the response to your counter offer”

It is December 16, and I have not heard back from them. I replied to the email this morning to thank them for considering my request. I am not sure why it would take them this long to respond to my counter offer when it took them 3 business days to extend this offer in the first place. Would I get a response from them before January at all? Would they rescind the offer, and give the job to someone else? This long wait is killing me especially when all I asked was $6,000 more.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to the question of "why it would take them this long to respond to my counter offer when it took them 3 business days to extend this offer in the first place".

Before the start of the search process there was probably a planned salary range for whoever they hired. The original offer was within that range. The decision that was made in 3 business days was to offer it to you rather than any of the other candidates.

One explanation of the delay is that your counter-offer was outside the range they had planned. Deciding whether to agree to it may require more approvals, and more delay, than deciding which candidate to offer the job at the planned salary.